# feh keys configuration not working

Tags: linux, feh

I am trying to have custom key bindings so that I can have vim like scrolling. Following is my `~/.config/feh/keys` file

```
scroll_right 
scroll_left 
scroll_up 
scroll_down 
scroll_up Up j
scroll_down Down k
scroll_left Left h
scroll_right Right l
```

But for some reason the key bindings are not working. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

These key bindings look right to me. I have the same setup.

If I were you I would check that `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is really unset or that it's set to `$HOME/.config`.

If `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is unset, then feh should default to `~/.config/feh/keys`, which is in your case perfectly fine.

```
echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME
```

Should tell you if it's unset and if feh looks in the right place

You could also try to edit `/etc/feh/keys` instead, to see if that at least works. However, that will not work if feh actually finds your config files in your home directory. This is because your own user settings take precedence and as a result `/etc/feh/` will be ignored.